# Got water on my laptob and now my screen looks like this (stuck/dead pixels?) but the laptop is still working fine

Tags: screen

Title says it all--but basically I wiped the water off and my laptop was fine for a few hours and then the next time I opened my laptop part of my screen was discoloured. I flipped my laptop upside overnight and when I turned my laptop on in the morning, it was all cleared up. However 8 hours later the screen is back to being pixelated. I don't exactly what it is and how to fix it. Should I get a new screen, fix it myself or buy a new laptop.
[image: picture]

Comment: How old is your Mac? Water damage is not covered under warranty. Your best bet would be to send it for repair with a general computer service store rather than with Apple.

Comment: It's a macbook air, 13 inch, two years old :) Thanks for the feedback

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) If you do decide to buy another computer, don't forget that this one may still be useful (e.g. connected to an external display, used for file/print/music sharing, etc). Also, if you haven't already, ensure you make a full working backup of your data. You should do this all the time anyway, but especially now as you may not have seen all the symptoms of your water damage yet.

Comment: Thank you! I'm buying an external hardrive tomorrow. This was very much a wake up call lol!